# How can I get the error message to display?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have some code here that looks up an image, but if the image isn't there it's supposed to display some error text.  All it does is show the broken image and doesn't use the error text.  Upon debugging i see the catch exception sees the 404 error but then it just skips right past the exception response text.  Here is my code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    checkMember(true);

    string acctNumber = Request["acctNum"];
    if (member.findAcct(acctNumber, "CheckImage") != null)
    {
        try
        {
            Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
            Response.BinaryWrite(((Member)member).checkImage(acctNumber, Request["ckNum"],DateTime.Parse(Request["date"]), Request["amt"], Request["checkSide"]));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.ContentType = "text";
            Response.Write("Error retrieving check image: "+ ex.Message);
        }
    }
    Response.End();
```

it just skips right over :

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Response.ContentType = "text";
    Response.Write("Error retrieving check image: "+ ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: Please show us code if `checkImage` method

Comment: Page_Load indicates it is ASP.NET

Comment: i would imagine with the 404 and Page_Load that this is a ASP.NET site

Comment: Maybe the `catch` never happens because there is no exception.

Comment: Let's remember that ASP.NET by itself can no longer be used. We have ASP.NET Webforms and ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: When i debug the catch exception shows the 404 error then just completely skips over the responses.

Comment: and ASP.NET MVC WebApi

Comment: @LéMuffinMan: the posted code could be used in any of the ASP.NET environments, I believe.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Sure, the code would compile, but MVC has no concept of page events. In other words if you refreshed the page this method would not automatically be hit.

Comment: @LéMuffinMan: you're right. Everything except the method signature would still be useful in all environments. It's not important to the question that this is in the Page Load event - what's important is that the code is running but there is no exception.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you aren't getting an exception, your if statement is just returning false?  Add an else to handle the error...

```
string acctNumber = Request["acctNum"];
if (member.findAcct(acctNumber, "CheckImage") != null)
{
     try
     {
         Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
         Response.BinaryWrite(((Member)member).checkImage(acctNumber, Request["ckNum"],DateTime.Parse(Request["date"]), Request["amt"], Request["checkSide"]));
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         Response.ContentType = "text";
         Response.Write("Error retrieving check image: " + ex.Message);
     }
}
else
{
     Response.ContentType = "text";
     //Exception Message can´t be referenced here
     Response.Write("Error retrieving check image");
}
```

Comment: The name 'ex' does not exist in the current context when adding the else

Comment: yeah but that´s no reason for a -1

Comment: @sine, that's precisely a reason for -1. It's not a punishment - it's a rating of the answer.

Comment: @Derek: I _did_ catch it. :-)

Comment: this was a simple copy-paste mistake, and everyone should be capable to see that! So I don´t think this a reason to downvote! And maybe you should give him the possiblity to correct that before downvoting

Comment: @sine: I removed the downvote after he corrected it. That's how it's meant to work.